# Abysmal I/O performance after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: hard-drive, performance, clone

I have a semi-regular task I do on my Ubuntu 16.04 workstation:  It has a second disk with Windows 7 on it.  It basically is a bare installation, which I sometimes boot up and let Windows Update run.  The idea is to use it for games, but, well, turns out I rarely have time.  I still keep it up to date.

This semi-regular task is cloning the disk using `ntfsclone` after I did such an update.  Look at it as "low-tech" snapshotting, because -alas- Windows cannot live inside an LVM volume.  (Well, it can, if it's being virtualized.)  I wrote a script to do this (and a few more things), because I'm lazy, but the command that takes most time and causes the problem is:

`ntfsclone -s -o /home/jorg/Images/$(date +%F).ntfsclone /dev/sdc2`

Where `/dev/sdc2` is the Windows partition and `/home/jorg/Images/` is an LVM volume, on a RAID1 comprised of `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.  All of these disks are normal hard disks, connected using SATA.

The problem that arises: when I do this, my workstation becomes totally and utterly unusable.  Responsiveness is simply horrible.  Even switching and logging into a virtual console (`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F1`) is unbearably slow.

This is not only using `ntfsclone` and that's why I suspect disk I/O.  When I do `dd`, a tool I often use to help people out with defective disks, the same happens.  It's even worse with `dd`, because that often goes over USB.  That said, I have used `dd` instead of `ntfsclone` as a test with the above setup, that is SATA-only, and it's just as bad.  Yes, I use the `bs` parameter in `dd` so that buffering is done correctly.

Thing is: while the computer slowed down in 14.04, it didn't become unusable.  It was just "a little slower", but browsing, email, terminal all were still bearable to use.

By now, I have also played with the different disk schedulers.  The schedulers supported are:

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
noop [deadline] cfq
```

Switching to `cfq` or `noop` didn't help.  ( `echo cfq > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`).

Some information about my machine:

```
root@tiger:~# uname -a
Linux tiger 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@tiger:~# dmidecode -t baseboard | grep -e Product -e Manufacturer
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: F1A75-V PRO
root@tiger:~# free -mh
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        1,7G        2,9G        154M         11G         13G
Swap:           31G          0B         31G
root@tiger:~# for disk in a b c ; do echo \[ Disk informatoin for \/dev\/sd$disk \] ; hdparm -I /dev/sd$disk | grep -e Model -e Transport ; done
[ Disk informatoin for /dev/sda ]
    Model Number:       ST1500DL003-9VT16L                      
    Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
[ Disk informatoin for /dev/sdb ]
    Model Number:       ST1500DL003-9VT16L                      
    Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
[ Disk informatoin for /dev/sdc ]
    Model Number:       WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0                   
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
```

I do realize my `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` aren't powerhouses, but they did fine under 14.04.

Is anyone also seeing abysmal performance when doing high I/O?  If so, did you find a workaround?

Comment: what kernel are you using? I had pretty bad problems with heavy IO (USB, SSD...). I was using the lowlatency kernel - which I actually do not need. After switching to the generic image it got much better.

Comment: well sorry about that - I just saw you have the uname -a output in your post. I will leave this comment here anyways, maybe it can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The [xanmod kernel](https://xanmod.org/) seemed to help. I was running 16.04 with ssd boot drive, gnome 3.2. I thought deadline scheduler would do it , but didn't seem to help much.  This is what I followed :  http://www.hecticgeek.com/2016/09/supercharge-ubuntu-16-04-lts-xanmod-kernel/

Comment: I'll look into it.  Not a big fan of replacing a quite critical component of the system.